# Form Validation in ASP .Net MVC with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to migrate my demo project to Angular as I am learning the same. But I faced a dilemma as whether to opt for  a razor view form validation while adding or rather updating some info on the client side
or to opt for Angular JS ?

So In Angular How would I achieve the same. 
Suppose I have  a _AddDetails.cshtml partial view :

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.Student
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend><strong>Create a record</strong></legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="createDetails" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

and in MVC I have opted for FluentValidation of the model.

The model looks like :

```
[FluentValidation.Attributes.Validator(typeof(StudentViewModelValidator))]
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    //Department Navigational Property
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

And the validation looks like :

```
public class StudentViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Student>
{
    public StudentViewModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("First Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^\D*$").WithMessage("Numbers are not allowed in First Name");
        RuleFor(m => m.LastName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Last Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^\D*$").WithMessage("Numbers are not allowed in Last Name");
        RuleFor(m => m.UserName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("User Name is required.")
            .Matches(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\$]*$").WithMessage("Only . and $ are allowed special characters in a user name");
        RuleFor(m => m.Password)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Password is required.")
            .Length(4, 10).WithMessage("Password should be 4 to 10 characters long")
            .Matches(@"^(?=(\D*\d){2,})(?=([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]))(?=[^\.\$\~\&]*[\.\$\~\&]).*").WithMessage("Password should contain at least 2 digits,a letter and at least a special character in it");

    }
```

But in angular if I re-build my view instead of this razor template how would I achieve these sort of complex regex validations ?
I know I have something like

```
ng-required
ng-minlength
ng-maxlength
```

But how would I achieve like the above razor validations?

Answer (score 1):

Use can use `ng-pattern` for `regex`

```
 <script>
      angular.module('ngPatternExample', [])
        .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
          $scope.regex = '\\d+';
        }]);
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <form name="form">
        <label for="regex">Set a pattern (regex string): </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="regex" id="regex" />
        <br>
        <label for="input">This input is restricted by the current pattern:     </label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="model" id="input" name="input"         ng-pattern="regex" /><br>
    <hr>
    input valid? = <code>{{form.input.$valid}}</code><br>
    model = <code>{{model}}</code>
      </form>
    </div>
```

**Reference :** 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the validation in my MVC project that uses angular, so I used the ng-pattern, I had a problem trying to include some special chars as valid for the user name:   "@", "_" and "-".

The only way I succeed was to add them as separate repeatable chars at the end of my pattern:

```
ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*[@('_')]*[@('-')]*[@('@')]*$/"
```

I hope this works for you.